# How to Remove "What is PayPal?" from PayPal option on checkout

Tags: checkout, payment, paypal

I have set-up PayPal as an option on my store. And by default on the payment option selection page next to the PayPal logo there is text stating "What is PayPal?" that links to the PayPal website.

I was wondering how I would remove the text and link.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is a Paypal link? The only "What is This" on the payment step of OnePage Checkout is for CVV code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it from this template file :

**/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/paypal/payment/mark.phtml**

Both paypal logo and text "What is Paypal" is coded in this file.

Ideally you should copy this file with same path in your theme and modify this file according to requirements.

Like if your theme is :

**/app/design/frontend/default/mytheme**

Then in its template folder create same path as "paypal/payment" and put modified mark.phtml here(If the path and file is already here you can directly modify it).

Comment: If you have SagePay Suite insatlled, the link is located in `Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/Block/Form/SagePayPayPal.php`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the `mark.phtml` file, I prerer to avoid displaying that file.

I copied the block `app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Block\Standard\Form.php` to my local (`app\code\local\...`) and changed

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_config = Mage::getModel('paypal/config')->setMethod($this->getMethodCode());
    $locale = Mage::app()->getLocale();
    $mark = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('core/template');
    $mark = new $mark;
    $mark->setTemplate('paypal/payment/mark.phtml')
        ->setPaymentAcceptanceMarkHref($this->_config->getPaymentMarkWhatIsPaypalUrl($locale))
        ->setPaymentAcceptanceMarkSrc($this->_config->getPaymentMarkImageUrl($locale->getLocaleCode()))
    ; // known issue: code above will render only static mark image
    $this->setTemplate('paypal/payment/redirect.phtml')
        ->setRedirectMessage(
            Mage::helper('paypal')->__('You will be redirected to the PayPal website when you place an order.')
        )
        ->setMethodTitle('') // Output PayPal mark, omit title
        ->setMethodLabelAfterHtml($mark->toHtml())
    ;
    return parent::_construct();
}
```

to

```
... the same
...
    $this->setTemplate('paypal/payment/redirect.phtml')
        ->setRedirectMessage(
            Mage::helper('paypal')->__('You will be redirected to the PayPal website when you place an order.')
        )
        ->setMethodTitle('Paypal (my title)');
    return parent::_construct();
}
```

adding my custom title and removing the mark file.