# Change PayPal Image in Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, paypal, paypal-express

I have tried everything to change the PayPal image at checkout in magento 1.9.1 CE.

We set up PayPal standard which also enables PayPal Express. We are not using any of the premium products from PayPal, just standard.

Apparently you can only change that image if you have one of their premium services, payflow pro, etc.

We want to switch the image to a credit card Paypal image.  Our customers don't know we can take any credit card though PayPal.

#### I tried editing:

mark.phmtl, shortcut.phmtl and logo,phmtl.

No luck, still shows the default logo.

Comment: have you tried this steps: http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-removechange-the-paypal-logo.html

Comment: share your site url

Comment: @Donika Yes I tried that, but the image remains the same. We are using the VES fashion template and have copied the logo.phtml to the appropriate directories of template, flushed the cache, but still the same.  It is reading the default image still from PayPal's servers.

Comment: @Manoj hothari Site not open to public yet.  The PayPal image we want to change is only at Checkout. How can I show you?  I have unlocked it temporaritly. Go here: https://www.alypsis.com/magento/checkout/cart/

Answer (score 4):

You can do it from this template file :

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/paypal/payment/mark.phtml
```

Both paypal logo and text "What is Paypal" is coded in this file.

Ideally you should copy this file with same path in your theme and modify this file according to requirements.

Like if your theme is :

```
/app/design/frontend/default/mytheme
```

Then in its template folder create same path as "paypal/payment" and put modified `mark.phtml` here (If the path and file is already here you can directly modify it).

Try this.

reference: [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6270/how-to-remove-what-is-paypal-from-paypal-option-on-checkout)

Comment: What part of the code in that file do I replace? I tried it but still shows paypal image from paypal.  I placed the file in the template folder.   

We are using the one-page checkout.  Would that make a difference on which files to edit?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from this template file:

**app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Block/Express/from.php**

```
From
protected function _construct()
    {
        $result = parent::_construct();
        $this->setRedirectMessage(Mage::helper('paypal')->__('You will be redirected to the PayPal website.'));
        return $result;
    }
To:-
protected function _construct()
    {
        $result = parent::_construct();
        $this->setRedirectMessage(Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Get 50% Cashback Upto Rs 400(for First Paypal users) Pay through Debit/Credit Card..'));
        return $result;
    }
```